# How to change color of Editor in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, enide

I know the preferences are under Preferences>General>Appearance, I played with the color themes and colors of TextEditor, I ended up with some ugly color scheme on top of the default white background (See attached). I tried to reset back to defaults, but nothing seems to get me back to the original default look. Attached is the ugly colors I am stuck with.[image]

Comment: This is EditBox (managing background colors) and is not covered by Eclipse FAQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you installed [Editbox](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/editbox#.VCUATq29p1w) plugin. Un-install this plug-in and manage colours with [eclipse themes](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/). Or try setting/preferences provided by Editbox plug-in itself. [Refer this](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/nodeclipse-editbox-background-colors-themes-highlight-code-blocks-c-java-javascript-python#.VCUAUK29p1w).

I think Editbox settings overrides the preferences in `Preferences>General>Appearance`.

You also can quickly enable/disable with such icon [image] on Eclipse main toolbar.

Select more themes from EditBox, read at https://github.com/Nodeclipse/EditBox

[image]

or

[image]

Comment: This answered my question. I did not remove the plugin, it was a matter of toggling the EditBox On/Off to get or not get the highlight on code blocks. I wasn't aware What Editbox did.

Answer (score 1):

You can get pre-defined color schemes in http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/

Download one you like and get started.

To reset your window perspective, you may go to:

```
 Window Menu -> Reset Perspective
```

Comment: I already had the themes downloaded, but the existing colors in the image seem to sit on top of whatever theme I pick. So, I figured it had to the the text edtiro, I tried resetting them to default, white...none seems to work. Resetting Perespective seem to keep the colors, just regains the settings and layouts but not colors.

Comment: This will not override EditBox