# Eclipse Text Editor text is highlighted in green?

Tags: eclipse, text-editor

I am experiencing a weird issue. My Eclipse editor is all green as shown in this photo here: [image: Text editor]

It's very strange because every time I restart my computer I still have this issue. Furthermore, when I check Preferences -> Restore Defaults, the issue is not fixed as my text editor settings are all set to default. Eclipse doesn't seem to say if there are any errors and I am not sure why this is happening. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Go to Preference > General > Apperance > Color & Fonts > Reset.

Comment: @ManhLe The Reset button is greyed out, I cannot seem to click it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you installed **EditBox** plugin. Either uninstall this plugin or disable it.
Check these posts

- [How to change color of Editor in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26053049/1391924)
- [Eclipse Background Color will not change OSX, Pydev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29739145/1391924)
- [Remove code block highlighting from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31563989/1391924)