# Remove code block highlighting from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I was working on Eclipse when I randomly pressed some key combination and my Eclipse Mars editor looks like this:

[image: Green background in editor]

I tried checking options in `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Color and Fonts` but to no avail.

How do I revert this change back to get a white background?

Comment: Is it possible that this is a plugin and not Eclipse itself? I think this feature was requested but available through plugins only. IMHO it's called "scope highlighting".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change color of Editor in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26044510/how-to-change-color-of-editor-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from Editbox plugin. You can toggle "Edit box" toolbar button.
Refer my answer to this question [How to change color of Editor in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26044510/how-to-change-color-of-editor-in-eclipse)

Comment: Exactly, that was it.